# Deserialize a JSON array into a Java object (Not a List nor a Collection) using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, migration, gson

I was previously using Gson and decided to move to Jackson for practical reasons.
Previously, I had a JSON deserializer that was deserializing an array of json objects into a single java object.

The json structure of the field is :

```json
{
    id: number,
    type: (0 | 1),
    allow: number,
    deny: number
}[]
```

And I need to deserialize this array into my own object: `PermissionOverwrites`.

Previously, I was using this code with Gson:

```java
JsonArray array = json.getAsJsonArray();
Map<Permissionable, Permissions> map = new HashMap<>();
 
for (JsonElement element : array) {
    JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
    Permissionable p = switch (object.get("type").getAsInt()) {
        case 0 -> new Permissionable.MockPermissionable(object.get("id").getAsLong()); 
        case 1 -> new Permissionable.MockPermissionable(object.get("id").getAsLong()); 
        default -> throw new JsonParseException("Unknown permissionable type");
    };
    Permissions perms = new Permissions(object.get("allow").getAsLong(), object.get("deny").getAsLong());
    map.put(p, perms);
}
 
return new PermissionOverwrites(map);
```

But now, with Jackson, I've got a JsonParser and a DeserializationContext and I can't find anything in any of the two files to parse an ArrayNode. Do you know any way I can do this using Jackson.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

`PermissionsOverwrites.java`

```java
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class PermissionOverwrites {

    private Map<Permissionable, Permissions> overwrites;
    
    public PermissionOverwrites(Map<Permissionable, Permissions> overwrites) {
        this.overwrites = overwrites;
    }
    
    public PermissionOverwrites() {
        this.overwrites = new HashMap<>();
    }
    
    public Map<Permissionable, Permissions> getOverwrites() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(overwrites);
    }
    
}
```

Example of the JSON object:

```json
[
    {
        "id": "111111111111111111",
        "type": "0",
        "allow": "01010",
        "deny": "10101"
    }
],
```

Comment: can you share the class `PermissionOverwrites` ?

Comment: Can you drop a sample of the json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses Jackson to do the same as your code that uses Gson:

```
JsonNode array = mapper.readTree(json);
for (JsonNode element : array) {
  Map<Permissionable, Permissions> map = new HashMap<>();
  Permissionable p = switch (element.get("type").asInt()) {
    case 0 -> new Permissionable.MockPermissionable(element.get("id").asLong());
    case 1 -> new Permissionable.MockPermissionable(element.get("id").asLong());
    default -> throw new JsonParseException("Unknown permissionable type", null);
  };
  Permissions perms = new Permissions(element.get("allow").asLong(), element.get("deny").asLong());
  map.put(p, perms);
}

return new PermissionOverwrites(map);
```

Here's [an article about how to work with Jackson JSON tree model](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-node-tree-model) .

Comment: By replacing `mapper.readTree(json)` with `JsonParser#readValueAsTree`, I actually got it working! Thank you very much!!!